# Slicing in python end+1/end-1 Creates problem

Tags: python

I am trying to find a certain encounter in a string with a start and end, copy that bit into a new string. For example:   s = "spamAspamBspam" to new_str = "AspamB"

I have tried the code below but since I need to +1 for the end I run into other problems. How can I solve this? thank you

I tried indexing but I get TypeError: string indices must be integers

my code;

```
s = "([)]"

o_p_index = s.find("(")
c_p_index = s.rfind(")")
o_c_index = s.find("{")
c_c_index = s.rfind("}")
o_b_index = s.find("[")
c_b_index = s.rfind("]")

if o_p_index == -1:
    o_b_index = 0
if c_p_index == -1:
    o_b_index = 0
if o_c_index == -1:
    o_c_index = 0
if c_c_index == -1:
    c_c_index = 0
if o_b_index == -1:
    o_b_index = 0
if c_b_index == -1:
    c_b_index = 0

print(o_p_index, c_p_index, o_c_index, c_c_index, o_b_index, c_b_index)

copy_list_p = s[o_p_index:c_p_index+1]
copy_list_b = s[o_b_index:c_b_index+1]
copy_list_c = s[o_c_index:c_c_index+1]

print(copy_list_p, "copy_list_p")
print(copy_list_c, "copy_list_c")
print(copy_list_b, "copy_list_b")
```

Terminal;

```
0 2 0 0 1 3
([) copy_list_p
( copy_list_c
[)] copy_list_b

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Defaulting all the not found characters to `0` is not right, since you can't distinguish between not finding them and finding them at the first position in the string.

Comment: If I default them to None, I get error when in slicing.

Comment: Do you have to do this with `find()` and slicing? Regular expressions would solve the problem more easily.

Comment: What are you supposed to return if you find an open without a matching close, or vice versa?

Comment: No, this is what I could think of. I'm not expert at this.

Comment: if string % 2 == 0 I run this part of the code. If not I return False right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `find`, use regular expressions.

```
import re

p_re = r'\(.*\)'
c_re = r'\{.*\}'
b_re = r'\[.*\]'

p_match = re.search(p_re, s)
c_match = re.search(c_re, s)
b_match = re.search(b_re, s)

if p_match:
    print(p_match.group())
else:
    print('parens not found')

if c_match:
    print(c_match.group())
else:
    print('curlies not found')

if b_match:
    print(b_match.group())
else:
    print('brackets not found')
```